# How do I create in Perl, an array of hashes of hashes, print them and add new array elements (i.e. another hash of hashes) in Perl?

Tags: arrays, perl, hash

It should look like this below,I want to do the following

1. Push new hash of hashes into this array
2. Print the entire array along with hash of hashes
3. Able to read off values of the sub hash elements

   ```
   my @AoH = (
     {
        undef
     },
     {
       Class1   => { hall_no => 10, Building_no => 1 },
       Subjects => { Math => 100, Physics => 200},
     },
     {
       Class2   => { hall_no => 10, Building_no => 2 },
       Subjects => { Chem => 100, Physics => 200},
     },
     {
       Class3   => { hall_no => 20, Building_no => 4 },
       Subjects => { Math => 100, Bio => 200},
     },    
   );
   ```

I tried this

1. for printing

   ```
   for $i ( 0 .. $#AoH ) {
     print "$i is { ";
     for $role ( keys %{ $AoH[$i] } ) {
       #print "$role=$AoH[$i]{$role} ";
       #DumperMsg("Results:",$AoH[$i]->"profile");
       print Dumper(%AoH[$i]);
     }
   ```
2. For pushing

   ```
   $AoH[3] = {Class4=> { hall_no => 20, Building_no => 1},};
   ```

No luck, new to Perl, thanks.

Comment: Is this a homework question? You need to explain what problems you are having—there's nothing especially wrong with what you have written

Comment: Doesn't say anything abou array of hashes of hashes, only array of hashes?

Comment: @user3380452: Yes. It does

Comment: @Borodin, haha too old to be doing h/w. It's a design problem, the problem is how do I dump the whole thing, like one would do for hash of hashes using Data::Dumper and the other problem is to add new array elements, this is for automating an embedded device, i just replaced the implementation with a simple example

Comment: There's an excellent tutorial on [references in Perl](http://perldoc.perl.org/perlref.html) in the [Perldoc online documentation](http://perldoc.perl.org)

Comment: @thanks David and other, I got the solution.

Answer (score 2):

1. Push new hash of hashes into this array.

   `push @array, \%hash_of_hashes;`
2. Print the entire array along with hash of hashes
3. Able to read off values of the sub hash elements

Those are two of the same thing. Read the [tutorial on Perl references](http://perldoc.perl.org/perlreftut.html). It'll help explain how references are used to build complex data structures.

```
#! /usr/bin/env perl
#
use strict;
use warnings;
use feature qw(say);

my @array = ...;

#
# This is the outer array which is not a reference.
#
for my $index ( 0..$#array ) {
    #
    # Each element is a reference to the hashes of hashes. Dereference
    #
    my %hashes_of_hashes = %{ $array[$index] };
    #
    # This is going through each element of the outer hash.
    # Each item is a key to a REFERENCE to another hash
    #
    for my $sub_hash_key ( sort keys %hashes_of_hashes ) {
        #
        # Dereference that inner hash
        #
        my %sub_hash = %{ $hashes_of_hashes{$sub_hash_key} };
        #
        # Finally, We have the inner hash. Each element contains
        # data and not another reference
        #
        for my $sub_key ( sort keys %sub_hash ) {
            #
            # This is how I refer to an item in that array of
            # Hashes of Hashes
            #
            print "\$array[$index]->{$sub_hash_key}->{$sub_key} = ";
            #
            # Since I dereferenced everything along the way, I can
            # easily print out the value via the sub_hash.
            #
            say $sub_hash{$sub_key};
        }
    }
}
```

The big trick is keeping your structure straight. Is this a key to a hash reference or data? Is this an array or a hash? Dereferencing your references can make the program easier to follow. I didn't have to do the constant dereferencing, but you can imagine that inner, inner `for` loop getting pretty hard to read with all those references of references.

There are three syntaxes to get the value in a reference:

1. `${${$array[$index]}{$sub_hash_key}}{$sub_key};`
2. `$array[1]{$hofh_key}{$hash_key}`
3. `$array[1]->{$hofh_key}->{$hash_key}`

The first way is using dereferencing to produce the correct value. It can get very difficult very quickly.

The second is a *shortcut* that allows Perl to assume the default dereferencing.

The third uses arrow syntax to *point* to the references. I like this way because it makes it very clear that I'm talking about a reference. You can't easily gloss over it.

You can sometimes also *dereference* by simply leaving off the curly braces. These are identical:

- `my %hash = %$hash_ref;`
- `my %hash = %{ $hash_ref };`

Again, I like the second way because it can be easy to miss the double sigil in front of *array*. Many people prefer the first because they think the syntax is clearer and easier to read.

If your data structure starts getting that complex, it's time to think about [Object Oriented Perl](http://perldoc.perl.org/perlootut.html)

Comment: @david-w  On Perl v5.18.2, `my %hash = %$array[$index];` and `my %hash = %{ $array[$index] };` are definitely not identical. The first version results in a syntax error `near "$array["`. I believe the curly braces are required. Can you confirm that it actually works without them for you?

Comment: Yes, this is a precedence issue. The `%$array[$index];` assumes the reference is `$array` and not `$array[$index]`. I need to make a hash reference for it first.

Answer (score 0):

Here is my take. But my suggestion is to sit down for half a day and do some tutorials found at [learn.perl.org](http://learn.perl.org/).

```
#!/usr/bin/env perl 

use strict;
use warnings;

use Data::Dumper;

# set up initial array of hashes
my @lessons = (
  {
    class_room => { hall_no => 10, building_no => 1 },
    subjects   => { Math => 100, Physics => 200},
  },
  {
    class_room => { hall_no => 10, building_no => 2 },
    subjects   => { Chem => 100, Physics => 200},
  },
);

# Push new hash of hashes into this array
push @lessons,      
      {
        class_room   => { hall_no => 20, building_no => 4 },
        subjects     => { Math => 100, Bio => 200},
      };

# Print the entire array along with hash of hashes
print Dumper( \@lessons );

# Able to read off values of the sub hash elements
foreach my $lesson ( @lessons ) {
    print "In building $lesson->{class_room}->{building_no} hall $lesson->{class_room}->{hall_no} we have the following classes:\n";
    while ( my ($subject, $level) = each %{$lesson->{subjects}} ) {
        print "$subject $level\n";
    }
    print "\n";
}
```

Comment: Thanks Barney.. Yes I will, more of a C, C++, Java person, started Perl yesterday, don't love it too much to be honest, Python is cleaner  isn't it..liked programming in Python sometime back,